# Newest version of javascript

Tags: javascript, version-control

Doing updates to my site and all the files seem to update ok, except the javascript files.

I think this is to do with the version, but try as I might I can't get version numbering to work.

```
  wp_register_script ('headjq', get_bloginfo('template_directory') . "/js/headjq.js");
        wp_enqueue_script('headjq');
```

Is there a way that I can automatically append a version number to the end to force the client to update the scripts?

Answer (score 1):

As the [Codex tells us](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script) you can add another parameter to the function that holds the version number.

```
wp_register_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer );
```

> **$ver**
>   String specifying the script version number, if it has one, which is concatenated to the end of the path as a query string. If no version is specified or set to false, then WordPress automatically adds a version number equal to the current version of WordPress you are running. If set to null no version is added. This parameter is used to ensure that the correct version is sent to the client regardless of caching, and so should be included if a version number is available and makes sense for the script.

So if you add a string, like `1.2.3` as fourth parameter, this is added to the end of your registered javascript file.